# fatal error: opening dependency file C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am getting the fatal error while compiling a program (using make). Is it because of some permission issues?

```
make -C src/hash_function
make[1]: Entering directory `....../src/hash_function'
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -funsigned-char -msse4.2  -I "/export/SOFTWARE/boost_1_61_0" -MMD -c farmhash.cpp -o ../../obj/farmhash.o
farmhash.cpp:1965:1: fatal error: opening dependency file ../../obj/farmhash.d: No such file or directory
 }  // namespace NAMESPACE_FOR_HASH_FUNCTIONS
 ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [../../obj/farmhash.o] Error 1
```

The Makefile looks like the following and I am bit confused how I handle `../../obj/farmhash.o`

```
CC       = g++
CCFLAGS  = -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -funsigned-char -msse4.2
LDFLAGS  =
INCLUDE  = -I "/export/SOFTWARE/boost_1_61_0"

EXE      = main
AUXFLAGS =
OPTFLAGS =
LIBS  = main.a index.a hash_map.a hash_function.a utils.a
LIBS := $(addprefix lib/,$(LIBS))

all: build/$(EXE)
run: all
         clear
         ./build/$(EXE) $(INPUT) $(QUERIES)

build/$(EXE): libs
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OPTFLAGS) $(LIBS) $(AUXFLAGS) -o $@

libs:
        $(MAKE) -C src/hash_function
        $(MAKE) -C src/hash_map
        $(MAKE) -C src/index
        $(MAKE) -C src/main
        $(MAKE) -C src/utils

.PHONY: clean

clean:
        rm -f build/main
        rm -f lib/*.a
        rm -f obj/*.d obj/*.o

rebuild: clean all
```

Comment: Your makefile should make sure the directory `../../obj` exists before running that command.

Comment: @aschepler Thanks !! I am not able to figure out that on the Makefile :(

Comment: shouldn't src/main be built after utils? try changing the order in which the libs are built

Comment: Yes, I tried that also. The Makefile has also a commented line which says # `The order here is based on library dependencies (left depends on right).`
`LIBS  = main.a index.a hash_map.a hash_function.a utils.a` . and I tried all the ordering but no luck.

Comment: what about the order used in the "libs" rule?

Comment: I used that order as well as all permutations